# How to horizontally align links with different widths, being responsive with a background image?

Tags: html, css

### Heya dear Stackers,

I need to make a web page where I'll have 9 links above an image.
With this [background](https://static.wixstatic.com/media/64fcdd_ebe7917745ee449c906e8bd87d853513.jpg/v1/fill/w_672,h_667,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/64fcdd_ebe7917745ee449c906e8bd87d853513.jpg) I'm using, I intend on making it responsive, as well as the links above each gray circle.

Imagine the following links' disposal:
[image]

 
I guess I could use like 3 different ***div*** elements, for example, where the ones containing **one** element would have width: 100%, the ones containing **two** elements would have width: 50% and the ones containing **three** elements would have width: 33%.
All of this, inside a main div element with a background image and fixed width and height (same as the image's size).

> Current HTML

```
<div class="list-part">
        <ul>
            <li id="w1"><a href="~/parceiros.cshtml">Parceiros</a></li>
            <li id="w2"><a href="~/phc-cs.cshtml">PHC CS</a></li>
            <li id="w2"><a href="~/phc-fx.cshtml">PHC FX</a></li>
            <li id="w3"><a href="~/consultoria.cshtml">Consultoria</a></li>
            <li id="w3"><a href="~/suporte.cshtml">Suporte</a></li>
            <li id="w3"><a href="~/desenv.cshtml">Desenvolvimento</a></li>
            <li id="w2"><a href="~/formacao.cshtml">Formação</a></li>
            <li id="w2"><a href="~/soltec.cshtml">Soltec</a></li>
            <li id="w1"><a href="~/financiamento.cshtml">Financiamento</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

> Current CSS

```
.list-part {
margin-top: 100px;
width: 672px;
height: 667px;
background: url(../media/solucoes_logo.jpg) no-repeat center;
background-size: contain;
}

.list-part ul {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

    .list-part ul li {
        list-style: none;
    }

        .list-part ul li a {
            color: red;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

            .list-part ul li a:hover {
                color: red;
            }

#w1 {
width: 100%;
height: 133px;
}

#w2 {
width: 48%;
height: 133px;
display: inline-block;
}

#w3 {
width: 33%;
height: 133px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

#### EDIT: So far, I almost did what I intended, excepting the vertical position of each link, which isn't in the centre of its respective circle, but on the top margin of it.

> [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9qoQ.png)

How can I dispose the links as the image shows, following the responsiveness of the background image?

Comment: what about link label? are they fix and will be fit in that circle?

Comment: I want the image to be responsive with the browser's window size, and independently of the image size, I want the links to stay in the centre of each gray circle, as disposed in the image I provided.

Comment: I already tried out some code that I may share with you, I'll edit my question as soon as I can!

Comment: **Question updated** - HTML, CSS and current result added.